# Have we already seen the collapses of the stability instability paradox?

Tags: nuclear-weapons

Although we have seen less wars between nations we have seen an increasing amount of civil wars, which can lead to wars between nations.

Comment: The [Stability-Instability paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability%E2%80%93instability_paradox)

Answer (score 1):

No, the paradox still hold.

As you said, we have civil wars and wars between nations but no war between nations that have nuclear weapons.

Comment: What about India and Pakistan? I guess we would need to go into a definition of war. But they both have nuclear weapons and have been at "war" / "conflict" for decades.

Comment: @Andrew17 Right. They are not considered great powers but they have been in conflict. Their most recent where small scale conflicts and localized in a specific region. I guess they would be reluctant to conduct large scale military operation because it might trigger a more virulent response.